# CRUD application in angularJs and spring

Tags: spring, angularjs

I want a simple CRUD appication in spring and angularJs. Please share any link where i can get the application with detailed application .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many links, some: [crudangular](https://github.com/vagnerbc/crudangular), a tutorial on how to write `REST` applications with angular: [league-tutorial](https://github.com/PaulL1/league-tutorial).

Other links, a [crud-seed](https://github.com/jarpineh/crud-seed), [ng-crud](https://github.com/hvogit/ng-crud), [angularJsCrud](https://github.com/developerinlondon/angularjs_crud).